# Access element having a specific attribute using XPath in VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath, namespaces

I am struggling since too many hours on getting the element having a specific attribute using XPath.

Hereunder is the wsdl from which I want to get the element  :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- Copyright Zuora, Inc. 2007 - 2010 All Rights Reserved. -->

<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:zns="http://api.zuora.com/" 
    xmlns:ons="http://object.api.zuora.com/"
    xmlns:fns="http://fault.api.zuora.com/"
    targetNamespace="http://api.zuora.com/">
    <types>


<schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://object.api.zuora.com/">
                <import namespace="http://api.zuora.com/" />
                <complexType name="zObject">
                <sequence>
                    <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="fieldsToNull" nillable="true" type="string" />
                    <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Id" nillable="true" type="zns:ID" />
                </sequence>
            </complexType>


            <complexType name="AccountingCode" >
                <complexContent>
                    <extension base="ons:zObject">
                        <sequence>
                            <element minOccurs="0" name="Category" nillable="true" type="string" />
                            <element minOccurs="0" name="CreatedById" nillable="true" type="zns:ID" />
                            <element minOccurs="0" name="CreatedDate" nillable="true" type="dateTime" />
                            <element minOccurs="0" name="GLAccountName" nillable="true" type="string"   />
                            <element minOccurs="0" name="GLAccountNumber" nillable="true" type="string"   />
                            <element minOccurs="0" name="Name" nillable="false" type="string" />
                            <element minOccurs="0" name="Notes" nillable="true" type="string" />
                            <element minOccurs="0" name="Status" nillable="true" type="string" />
                            <element minOccurs="0" name="Type" nillable="false" type="string" />
                            <element minOccurs="0" name="UpdatedById" nillable="true" type="zns:ID" />
                            <element minOccurs="0" name="UpdatedDate" nillable="true" type="dateTime" />
                        </sequence>
                    </extension>
                </complexContent>
            </complexType>

            <complexType name="AccountingPeriod" >
                <complexContent>
                    <extension base="ons:zObject">
                        <sequence>
                            <element minOccurs="0" name="CreatedById" nillable="true" type="zns:ID" />
                            <element minOccurs="0" name="CreatedDate" nillable="true" type="dateTime" />
                            <element minOccurs="0" name="EndDate" nillable="true" type="date" />
                            <element minOccurs="0" name="FiscalYear" nillable="true" type="int" />
                            <element minOccurs="0" name="Name" nillable="true" type="string" />
                            <element minOccurs="0" name="Notes" nillable="true" type="string" />
                            <element minOccurs="0" name="StartDate" nillable="true" type="date" />
                            <element minOccurs="0" name="Status" nillable="true" type="string" />
                            <element minOccurs="0" name="UpdatedById" nillable="true" type="zns:ID" />
                            <element minOccurs="0" name="UpdatedDate" nillable="true" type="dateTime" />
                        </sequence>
                    </extension>
                </complexContent>
            </complexType>
        </schema>
    </types>
</definitions>
```

There are multiple namespace define in this wsdl :

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:zns="http://api.zuora.com/" 
xmlns:ons="http://object.api.zuora.com/"
xmlns:fns="http://fault.api.zuora.com/"
targetNamespace="http://api.zuora.com/">
```

Here under is my very simple piece of code. Iam pretty sure that my issue is on namespace but despite searching an trying numerous solution I could not solve it :

```
Public Sub constituteLocalDictionnary()

    Dim pathWsdlFile As String
    pathWsdlFile = My.Settings.ZuoraUrlWSDL

    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    doc.Load(pathWsdlFile)



    Dim nsmgr As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/")
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("ons", "http://object.api.zuora.com/")

    Dim myXmlPath As String
    myXmlPath = "//ns:complexType[@name='" & ZuoraWsdlObjectsList(1) & "']"

    Dim root As XmlElement = doc.DocumentElement
    Dim node As XmlNode = root.SelectSingleNode(myXmlPath, nsmgr)

End Sub
```

Comment: All my polite formula gone after copy and paste to validate this post. There was some Hi all... Thanks a lot for any help... things like that :) Sorry for the rought aspect of the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used wrong namespace to reference `complexType` element. `complexType` in fact inherits *default namespace* from its parent element `schema` instead of the root element, since the parent is nearer hence overrides default namespace from outer elements context :

```
<schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://object.api.zuora.com/">
    <import namespace="http://api.zuora.com/" />
    <complexType name="zObject">
        ....
    </complexType>
    ....
</schema>
```

Try this way :

```
....

Dim nsmgr As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns2", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")

Dim myXmlPath As String
myXmlPath = "//ns2:complexType[@name='" & ZuoraWsdlObjectsList(1) & "']"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That solved my issue. And I understand now better how to address correctly name spaces.

Comment: @stef You are welcome. Don't forget to accept answer that you see more appropriate ([read more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work))

Answer (score 0):

Code is very simply using Xml Linq

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq

Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)
        Dim results = doc.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "complexType").Select(Function(y) New With { _
                .name = y.Attribute("name"),
                .elements = y.Descendants(y.Name.Namespace + "element").Select(Function(z) New With { _
                     .minOccurs = CType(z.Attribute("minOccurs"), Integer), _
                     .name = CType(z.Attribute("name"), String), _
                     .nillable = CType(z.Attribute("nillable"), Boolean), _
                     .type = CType(z.Attribute("type"), String) _
                 }).ToList()
        }).ToList()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thanks but I went with XPath solution on ce my name space has been solved. I am able to do the same as much simply with XPAth than you did with Linq ("//ns:complexType[@name='" & ZuoraWsdlObjectsList(1) & "']/ns:complexContent/ns:extension/ns:sequence/ns:element") and a selectNodes instead of SelectSingleNode

Comment: My solution is generic and will work with any namespace.  I extract the namespace from the xml data rather than hard coding the namespace.  My solution also gets an array of complexType while you solution only gets a single complexType.

Comment: Indeed you're right. I did not precise this but in My solution, I need to go straight to specific complecType elemnt having name equal to something (stored in multidimensional array ZuoraWsdlObjectsList) and then I get all element from there in another array, which is exctacly what I need. But for sure I'll give a look to your solution and maybe I'll change my mind. :) Thanks you very much.

Comment: You can add a WHERE to get a specific name.